# Edittext in ListView lost cursor

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I have a `ListView` contains multi `EditText`. Sometimes, when I scroll and focus on `EditText`, the cursor disappears although the keyboard is showing and I can input the character normally. The cursor just appears when I put the first character.

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_nutri_lo"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_corner"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/et_corner_radius"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_small_h"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:minEms="3"
            android:maxEms="6"
            android:gravity="right|bottom"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:filterTouchesWhenObscured="false"
            />
```

Do you know what's wrong?

Thanks

Comment: can you able to show the properties of your edittext ?

Comment: @Sreekanthss: I updated my edittext above

Comment: give this line to your listview android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"  or android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"

Comment: @Sreekanthss It doesn't work

Comment: set focusable and focusableInTouch mode to true

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tatRatatouille: Not work at all

Comment: when you tap on the edittext, set the focusable to true through code, or else check if there is a showCursor method

Comment: also try setting requestFocus to true  if it helps

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tatRatatouille: nothing is helpful. It sometimes happens, not always, and edittext is in listview

Comment: oh ok, then i am not really sure wht next to try :( sorry

Answer (score 4):

Have you by any chance set an OnFocusChangeListener? If yes, try the following:

```
view.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
        [YOUR CODE HERE]
        view.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus); // Fix for text selection handle not disappearing
    }
});
```